# How to make a category inside a category with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, categories

I want to build an app that manages your photos into categories and you only put at first their path and then with keywords you access those photos. I got stuck when I have to make a sub category. I tried

`path_and_image = {user_answer : new_list, new_list : path_LiL}`

Where user_answer is the main category, new_list is the sub category/categories and path_LiL is their paths. It gave me traceback with **TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**. I do not know how to solve this, I hope someone can get my problem solved.

I tried other things too, like a function from stackoverflow too:

```
                                        [lista_noua],
                                    [lista_noua] ,
                                        [path_LiL]]

                    def make_trie(path_and_image):
                        root = dict()
                        for i in path_and_image:
                            current_dict = root
                            for letter in i:
                                current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(letter, {})

                        return root
                    trie = make_trie(path_and_image)
                    print(trie)
```

It still giving the same error.

Comment: all your categories have subcategory? and how many levels? a nested dictionary will help your but you're doing it wrong.

Comment: fix indentation

Answer (score 0):

You try to have a list as a key in dictionary. Specifically `new_list` in the second element of dictionary. That is your error.

A good solution:

`path_and_image = {user_answer : new_list, 'paths': path_LiL}`

You noticed that `'paths'` is a string.

Comment: Then you indeed need a nested dictionary.

Comment: I want that every string from the new_list to have its path as an image, cuz I can't know what an user will put to replace the string in there to be the keyword, I mean if I have a category called lessons there I wanna have math and english, from there I wanna put for each category some photos path and then when the user say lessons and then at another input math, the program should open to him one image or more depends on how many did he put there, but I can't know their key word to put it in my dict. But I will try it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use nested dictionary? (The list can not be a key as it is not hashable, i.e its value can change over time, only Immutable objects like string, tuple can be used as keys)

---

### Continuing to the answer:

Consider this-

```
Category Colors
  | Red
  | Pink
  | Blue
Category Material
  | Matte
  | Polish
  | Plain
Category Other
  | ...
```

#### Code

```
colors = ['Red', 'Pink', 'Blue']
material = ['Matte', 'Polish', 'Plain']

categories = {'colors': colors, 'material': material}
```

---

Even if you have more levels - you should go like...

```
Category Colors
  | Red
     | Dark Red
     | Light Red
  | Pink
     | Dark Pink
     | Light and Dark Pink
  | Blue
Category Material
  | Matte
  | Polish
  | Plain
Category Other
  | ...
```

#### Here,

```
colors = {'Red': ['Dark Red', 'Light Red'],
          'Pink': ['Dark Pink', 'Dark & Light Pink'],
          'Blue': ['Blue']}

material = {'Matte': ['Matte'],
            'Polish': ['Polish'],
            'Plain': ['Plain']}

categories = {'colors': colors, 'material': material}
```

Of course, it deserves better answer - but now you can get to work with it.

But remember, there should be consistency, if you are having more than one levels in one category then other category should also have the same data structure otherwise you will run into problems while iterating through them.

Thanks!

Comment: Well I dont know the user input to can pre-made the categories that's why I don't put the string cuz i dont know it already. Thanks anyway I will try it.